# BootStrap in laravel blade templateEngine

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

i'm using Blade template Engine in Laravel. and i want to desing forms with twitter bootstrap.

My sample Form

```
@section('content')
<div style='margin:20px auto;height:100px;width:300px;background-color: #fff;line-height: 1.5px'>
    {{ Form::open(array('route'=>'auth', 'method'=>'post')) }}

        {{ Form::text('username', Input::old('username'), array('placeholder'=>'Username', 'id'=>'username')) }}

        {{ Form::password('password', array('placeholder'=>'Password', 'id'=>'password')) }}

        {{ Form::submit('Login', array('id'=>'submit')) }}

    {{ Form::close() }}
</div>
@stop
```

in this sample. how to setting that for bootstrap?

Comment: View the HTML generated, and then add Bootstrap-specific `<div>`s around it, like `<div class="form-group">` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply the Bootstrap style to your forms, you need to pass the class "form-control" into your blade:

```
{{ Form::text('username', Input::old('username'), array('placeholder'=>'Username', 'id'=>'username', 'class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Styling laravel/blade forms with bootstrap:

```
["class"=>"form-control"]
```